# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, can not use apt-get -f install

Tags: 14.04, apt

Anyone can help me please.

I just want to install letsencrypt, then i use the common command like sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. But it return error to me, and it lets me try apt-get -f install.

I can not use apt-get -f install.

Thanks for your advice.

[image]

Comment: What exactly did you tried to install before noticing this error? If you were following a guide/tutorial, please [edit] and post it.

Comment: I just want to install letsencrypt, then i use the common command like  sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. But it return error to me, and it lets me try apt-get -f install.

Comment: `apt-get -f install` is something you wouldn't normally use/need. If you do then there's a problem. Please [edit] again and describe **exaclty** what you did before getting this error.

Answer (score -1):

please try:

```
 `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archive/lock`
 `sudo dpkg--cofigure -a`
```

I had same problem and they worked for me

Comment: Like medicine, what works for you often does not for others. In this case this couldn't work because it has nothing to do with the problem: This removes a lock (which doesn't exist, apt works but gives errors) yet the problem is at the software sources.